# why we need to put additionally 'get' and 'set' while creating object?

Tags: javascript

I've created getter and setter functions like so:

```
var obj = {
    a: 7, 
    get b() {
        return 1;
    },
    set c(a) {
        this.a = 2;
    }
}
```

I then try to call functions b and c. 
If I call `obj.c()`, the following error appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.c is not a function(…)

same for `obj.b()`.

What does 'get' and 'set' do when creating objects?

Comment: what you are having is getter and setter functions so just accessing `alert(o1.b)` will call the `b()` function

Comment: same way setting `o1.c=4` will call the setter function

Comment: `b` and `c` are not functions

Comment: @Glubus Lack of basic research?  A search for "javascript get set" gives the top two results as the MDN pages for [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) which give some good reading.  Then at least a more specific question may arise if further problems are had with those explanations.

Comment: Hmm I guess, though I believe OP might have googled here and there. It seems like his english isn't too great, so he might not understand proper documentation as easy. And at least he actually posted what he had done, explained what he did not understand. If you find this too much off topic you must have a hard time with keeping up downvoting all the questions posted on here, even though you're probably in the right.

Answer (score 2):

The `get` and `set` keywords are for creating *getter* and *setter* functions. You don't call them explicitly however — they're called *implicitly* when you make an assignment to a property (the setter) or retrieve the value of a property (the getter).

The getter would be called when you do something like

```
var x = o1.b;
```

The setter would be called when you do

```
o1.c = 12;
```

Note that you don't "have to" use setter and getter functions; they're optional, and they're an ES2015 feature. Older JavaScript environments do not support that mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Because the entire point of getters and setters is for you to NOT use them as a function, and instead have a function operate behind the scenes as you use them to get/set properties.

For example, this makes it so that `obj1.b` when read will be whatever you set it to plus 100, using obj1.a to store that value:

```
var o1 = {
   a:7, 
   get b(){return this.a;},
   set b(val){this.a=val+100;}
}

alert(o1.b); // 7 cuz nothing changed yet
o1.b = 10;
alert(o1.b); // now 110
```